# Have a Crystal Report but not the XSD - how to extract it?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, xsd

I have a Crystal Report used in an ASP.NET web application that I've just come into a project I'm assessing/turning around.

The reports are called from a web page or web service and are sent an ADO.NET dataset - using ReportDocument.SetDataSource for some tables with a relation etc - all defined largely in code - initially loaded from the database, but it looks like some data is even altered after load in the datasets. (don't ask)

I have several XSDs (and a whole bunch of source repository history) but none seem to match the report, and trial and error to find the right one is taking way too long.

I have added some data in the code, but I cannot get the report to allow me to add fields until I update the report data source, but I don't have the original XSD to point it to.  I have to get the report updated to solve immediate needs and then I can address the strategic direction of refactoring this design/architecture.

Is there a way to extract the XSD from the Crystal Report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used `ds.WriteXmlSchema()` to write the schema to a file and then pointed the report at the file to fix it up.